# What Happens if Uncharged VFD is Connected to Charged DC Bus

Tags: vfd

if the dc fuse of the uncharged drive is closed when the dc bus of other drives is charged , what happens ? Is there any risk of damaga capacitor ? As I know, capacitor can stand to very high currents thanks to its nature. I know the fuse might clear but if the fuse is oversized, is there any risk for capacitor ?

Answer (score 2):

It is very possible that the capacitors will be damaged. They have a maximum current ratings and I am sure that connecting 400 V will exceed the rated current by a lot, as well as exceeding the rated current of any normal switch, etc.

It is also possible that the fuse will blow. But not guaranteed since the current is not sustained (more like a pulse current). As I have explained before, the fuse must be sized according to the wire. You should not oversize the fuse larger than dictated by the wire size used. But you can use a "slow blow" fuse.

I definitely recommend that you do NOT plan to do this. You should not be switching DC to and from the VFD's unless the manufacture can confirm that it is OK. When I asked Hitachi about this, they mentioned that the inverter I was looking at does not have any inrush limiting on the DC bus. The inrush limiting is on the AC input. If you switch the DC to the VFD, you will need to arrange your own precharge solution or inrush limiter.

But you shouldn't need to switch the DC under normal operation. You can turn the VFD on and off using low voltage signals and leave the DC bus powered up all the time. You should have a switch on the DC bus, but it is not for hot switching. It is just a disconnect for safety if you need to work on the VFD wiring.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer. Appreciated

Comment: Btw, I was thinking that the inrush limiter is for protecting the front end of vfd but as I understand from your respond, it also protects capacitor from damage right ?

Comment: "It is possible that the capacitors will be damaged." could be an understatement. I have seen capacitors explode due to increasing the supply voltage too quickly. The supply was just a variable transformer and a bridge rectifier. I turned the knob slowly to charge the bank of capacitors. At some point, I turned the knob a bit too quickly. Two or three capacitors exploded and the transformer was damaged.

Comment: Yeah. Large inrushes cause all kinds of problems.